# "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" Redux

Tags: php, mysql

An associate and I are tasked with modifying some PHP code. We have things set up and working properly on a server. On our local computers where we are wanting to make the changes, when we attempt to make a call to `mysql_connect`, we get an error of "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it." This question has been asked previously... and answered. But the answers didn't help.

Previous Proposed Solutions:

Solution 1: "Make sure the services are working." They are. On the server, the call works just fine with localhost as the connecting address.

Solution 2: "Fix your password." Again, not an issue. On the server connection to localhost, there's no issue.

Solution 3: "Firewall/antivirus blocking." On a whim, my associate used a telnet program to hit the ip/port combination. Connection was made. Obviously telnet won't be able to do anything useful in this situation. He just wanted to establish that a firewall wasn't shutting us out.

Solution 4: "Use mysqli, not mysql." This isn't a practical option for us. It's a complete system we're working with and there's no budget to make those changes. Further, we did try the initial connect using `mysqli_connect`. Rather than an immediate error, it locked and timed out.

Solution 5: "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'user'@'11.22.33.44' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';" Didn't work.

There's something outside the usual that needs to be done, but we're at a loss to know what to try next. Suggestions?

Comment: _Target machine actively refused_ The server is not running or the Firewall is blocking acccess

Comment: What version of PHP are you running

Comment: IF _There's something outside the usual that needs to be done_ THEN we are going to find it very difficult to help without root access

Comment: generally, you'll want to use a local mysql server for testing and debugging. Don't hit the live server. Sounds like IT is preventing you from hosing the company

Comment: RiggsFolly, you didn't notice points #1 and #3?

Comment: Garr, that might be our only option. Have a duplicate of the db on local machines for testing.

Comment: I did notice #1 and #3 However that is the most likely reason. What we dont know is that you can be relied upon to have correctly checked either of those possibilities